# ActiveRecord read replica for reporting queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails/ActiveRecord application that occasionally executes some heavy read-only queries against the application's models for ad-hoc admin/reporting purposes. I currently send these queries to a separate read-replica database endpoint using the [seamless_database_pool](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool) gem so these queries do not add load to the primary database. However, this setup adds a constant runtime dependency on the replica, reducing my application's availability - whenever the replica goes offline for maintenance, the entire site returns 503 errors on *any* request, even though most requests never query the read-replica at all.

How can I connect to a read replica for ad-hoc reporting queries on ActiveRecord models without affecting the availability of my application? Is there another database-adapter gem that handles this use-case explicitly?

Or, (even better) is it possible to accomplish this directly using ActiveRecord? I know that it's possible to connect to a separate database by calling `#establish_connection` in order to direct a *specific* model to a separate database across *all* controller actions, but for my use case I need to connect to a separate database across *all* models, but only for *specific* controller actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this issue by modifying the [`seamless_database_pool`](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool) gem to relax the runtime dependency on the read-replica when only the master connection is being used. See the relevant [issue](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool/issues/38) and [PR](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool/pull/39).